# Find and Update a WPF TextBox's Bound Property (From the TextBox)

Tags: c#, wpf

Say I have a text box like this:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding MyBoundProperty, Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

Is there an easy way to find and set "MyBoundProperty" in code behind?

I am working in a custom attached property for a TextBox (catching the OnTextBoxKeyUp event) and want to set the property directly in some scenarios (when a scan happens).

Answer (score 0):

If it's two-way binding, changing the Text property of the TextBox should update the source.